# all number have been rebeated less than N times

Tags: java, arrays

i'm tring to return an array that have all number have been rebeated less than N times.

expected output :  1,4

this is my cod :

-- Main --

```
 int[] data = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5};
    int n = 1;
        Solution.solution(data, n);
```

-- class Solution --

```
public static int[] solution(int[] data, int n) {
        
        int l =  data.length, count = 0;
        int[] Narr = new int[l];
        
        for(int i =0 ; i < l; i++){
            count = 0;
            
            for(int j=1 ; j < l ; j++){
                if(data[i] == data[j]){
                    count++;
                }
                
                if(j == l-1){
                    
                    if(count < n){
                         Narr[i] = data[i];
                         System.out.println(Narr[i]);
                     } 
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        return Narr;
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is how to return an array that have all number have been rebeated less than N times. this cod above is colse but  wrong .

Comment: I'm working on that

Comment: Please [*edit the question*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73026513/edit) - **describe the problem** - what output you're getting, what output is expected. Clarify the definition of *repeated less than N times*. In your example, you're passing `n=1`, less than `1` means `0`... Maybe you've meant *less or equal to N*.

Comment: I was assuming he meant less or equal to N, otherwise the expected output wouldn't match.

Comment: @sm3sher In the code OP uses condition `if (count < n)` - not `<=`, so another possibility there's a mistake in the input sample and `n` should be `2`. None of the readers of the question should guess, the problem should be clear.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko You're absolutely right. I have a habit of assuming since lots of new questions lack quality and clearance.

Answer (score 0):

I would break this down to multiple steps.

First lets create a `countMap` that holds track of all the occurrences:

```java
int[] data = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5};
int n = 1;

Map<Integer, Long> countMap = Arrays.stream(data).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(countMap); // {1=1, 2=2, 3=3, 4=1, 5=2}
```

Now all we need to do is to check for the condition `count <= n`:

```java
List<Integer> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
countMap.forEach((integer, count) -> {
    if (count <= n) resultList.add(integer);
});

System.out.println(resultList); // [1, 4]
```

And last but not least converting the `list` back to `array`:

```java
// {1, 4}
int[] resultArray = resultList.stream()
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .toArray();
```